# SQL Server Join Tables By Combining 2 Columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

This sounds ridiculously easy but I've tried so many different approaches. This query is just set up weird and I'm trying to JOIN it but there's not a common column I can do that with. There is, however, a LastFirst column (consists of LastName then FirstName) written in the context of DOE, JOHN. Then on the columns I'm trying to join that with it's just FirstName (John) and LastName (Doe).

I'm actually trying to select data from 4 tables that all are returning 1 row. These 2 tables can be joined:

```
SELECT 
    RIFQuery.*, 
    _Employee.EmployeeLastName + ', ' + _Employee.EmployeeFirstName AS EmployeeLastFirst, 
    _Employee.EmployeeTitle, _Employee.Phone As EmployeePhone, 
    _Employee.EmailAddress As EmployeeEmailAddress 
FROM 
    RIFQuery 
INNER JOIN 
    _Employee ON RIFQuery.CreatedBy = _Employee.AutoNumber 
WHERE 
    RIFQuery.Autonumber = 1
```

This one has nothing to join with so I'll probably union it and null remaining columns:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblOrganization
```

This is the table that contains LastName and FirstName that I'm trying to join with RIFQuery.LastFirst:

```
SELECT 
    Gender As ClientGender, DOB As ClientDOB, SSN As ClientSSN
FROM 
    _Clients 
WHERE 
    _Clients.LASTNAME = left(RIFQuery.LastFirst, len(RIFQuery.LastFirst)-CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(RIFQuery.LastFirst))) 
     AND _Clients.FIRSTNAME = ltrim(substring(RIFQuery.LastFirst, len(RIFQuery.LastFirst)-CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(RIFQuery.LastFirst))+2, len(RIFQuery.LastFirst)))
```

In that WHERE statement the code will split the LastFirst column and get the row by searching their LastName and FirstName. I'm wondering if there's a way I can write that into a JOIN? Otherwise I can probably UNION and null remaining columns but it will look very ugly.

UPDATE

I tried 2 suggestions from here and both result in a syntax error. I forgot to mention that I'm executing this code inside Microsoft Access VBA and trying to retrieve a DAO.RecordSet. I had to remove some table names in the SELECT statement to get past a syntax error from there, so maybe I should update the question to reflect MS ACCESS and not SQL Server, although only the query is the only pure Access object and the rest are linked ODBC tables to SQL Server.

UPDATE

Just one of those issues where I can't sleep until it's fixed and will obsess until it is. If I take out all _Employee references (from SELECT and JOIN statements), it wants to work but errors about too few parameters. I just now know this is related to _Employee. Getting different results from applying parentheses and just hoping I'll get lucky and hit on it.

The error is caused by this line:

```
INNER JOIN [_Employee] ON [_Employee].[AutoNumber] = [RIFQuery].[CreatedBy]
```

I get this error:
"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression".

As seen in this screenshot:
[image: Error Screenshot]

Here's my latest query I'm playing with, minus the parentheses:

```
str = "SELECT [RIFQuery].*, " & vbCrLf & _
"       ([_Employee].[EmployeeLastName] & ', ' & [_Employee].[EmployeeFirstName]) AS [EmployeeLastFirst], " & vbCrLf & _
"       [_Employee].[EmployeeTitle], " & vbCrLf & _
"       [_Employee].[Phone] AS [EmployeePhone], " & vbCrLf & _
"       [_Employee].[EmailAddress] AS [EmployeeEmailAddress], " & vbCrLf & _
"       [_Clients].[Gender] AS [ClientGender], " & vbCrLf & _
"       [_Clients].[DOB] AS [ClientDOB], " & vbCrLf & _
"       [_Clients].[SSN] AS [ClientSSN] " & vbCrLf & _
"FROM [_Clients] " & vbCrLf & _
"      INNER JOIN [RIFQuery] ON [RIFQuery].[LastFirst] = [_Clients].[LASTNAME] & ', ' & [_Clients].[FIRSTNAME] " & vbCrLf & _
"      INNER JOIN [_Employee] ON [_Employee].[AutoNumber] = [RIFQuery].[CreatedBy] " & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE [RIFQuery].[Autonumber] = 1;"
```

For debugging purposes, if I remove those last 2 lines and the _Employee SELECT statements, it'll process the query without a problem. If anyone has any ideas just let me know.

I was focused on that RIFQuery JOIN statement being the culprit for the longest time but I've found that simply is not the issue any more. With that said, this thread has been essentially solved and I appreciate the help.

Comment: It would probably be much easier to concatenate the two separate columns together for the join, rather than splitting the LastFirst column, e.g. `SELECT ... FROM _Clients LEFT JOIN RIFQuery ON RIFQuery.LastFirst  = CONCAT(_Clients.LASTNAME, ', ', _Clients.FIRSTNAME)`

Comment: I thought that was for sure going to work but it's giving a syntax error. I've updated the question above.

Comment: Sorry, I only saw the SQL Server tag and not MS Access. The concatenation operator in Access is `&` so you would need to do something like `ON RIFQuery.LastFirst = _Clients.LASTNAME & ', ' &_Clients.FIRSTNAME`

Comment: My mistake, I should've specified that originally. Unfortunately that's still throwing a syntax error. I noticed the &_Clients was missing a space so I tried it with a space (& _Clients) but still the same error. Still playing around with it.

Comment: I think you are missing parentheses in your joins. Access only allows one join before you need to start adding parentheses to make it valid syntax. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23762109/1048425) for more details

Comment: Awesome that's definitely getting me somewhere from a quick attempt. Reading more into it now and will try again. Also it's referencing RIFQuery on the _Clients JOIN before RIFQuery was JOINED. I'm not sure if that matters, though I did change the order and went back to reading that post when it didn't work. Thanks I'm sure I'll get it.

Comment: Can't you add the `_Clients` PK to RIFQuery? Then you could join on that. Your solution can't use indices what will lead to poor performance when the data grows. In addition, you shouldn't rely on Names to be unique.

Comment: I absolutely would if I had full reign but my client is pretty hesitant about changing any of his code, even if it's the smallest change. Obviously there's no way anything could break from that so I think I'll blame OCD with a lack of confidence on this one. I also thought about names not being unique and that might be removed when I review it with him, definitely will suggest adding _Clients PK.

Comment: So um... Turns out there was another query of the same name but with an appended _Expanded in the name. The project details were more of "look at these functions as a guideline" instead of "use these specific objects". A lot of this is getting nixed but I didn't think twice because I've been assigned to projects with poor table/query design in the past and needed to get crafty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Access is using a slightly different syntax than SQL Server when it comes to using more than one JOIN. You could leave out the JOIN with the `_Clients` (making it a *cross join*) and move that condition to the WHERE clause, which would make the query look like this (and which would allow you to display the design window for the query without any problem)

```
SELECT RIFQuery.*, 
  EmployeeLastName + ', ' + EmployeeFirstName As EmployeeLastFirst, 
  EmployeeTitle, Phone As EmployeePhone, EmailAddress As EmployeeEmailAddress, 
  Gender As ClientGender, DOB As ClientDOB, SSN As ClientSSN
FROM _Clients, RIFQuery INNER JOIN _Employee ON RIFQuery.CreatedBy = _Employee.AutoNumber
WHERE RIFQuery.LastFirst = _Clients.LASTNAME & ", " & _Clients.FIRSTNAME;
```

Instead of assembling the query string in VBA just for being able to change the parameter value, I suggest to save the following query as an Access object (maybe `qryRIF`):

```
PARAMETERS lgRIF Long;
SELECT RIFQuery.*, 
  EmployeeLastName + ', ' + EmployeeFirstName As EmployeeLastFirst, 
  EmployeeTitle, Phone As EmployeePhone, EmailAddress As EmployeeEmailAddress, 
  Gender As ClientGender, DOB As ClientDOB, SSN As ClientSSN
FROM _Clients, RIFQuery INNER JOIN _Employee ON RIFQuery.CreatedBy = _Employee.AutoNumber
WHERE RIFQuery.LastFirst = _Clients.LASTNAME & ", " & _Clients.FIRSTNAME
  AND RIFQuery.Autonumber = [lgRIF];
```

In your VBA code, you can use code like the following to grab the QueryDef object, assign the parameter value and open a recordset:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs!qryRIF
    !lgRIF = lgRIF
    With .OpenRecordset()
        ' ... your code ...
        .Close
    End With
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: Fantastic! I can't thank you enough! I've been on this for so many straight hours and hate asking for help as it is, but there's so many caveats to Access syntax I had no clue about it. A weight has been lifted off my shoulders, really, a huge thank you!

Comment: I did go with your strategy to save the query as an Access object, really nice idea and so much slicker. Excellent explanation as well, I've truly learned a lot from this.