# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression on 3 way Inner Join

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm seeing the following error message: **Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'm.AccountNumber=a.AccountNumber
INNER JOIN ActivityTable_2M b On a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber'** when writing the following query to my VBA program:

```
SELECT m.CaseManager, SUM(m.Lead) AS 'Total Leads', 
COUNT(a.Description) AS 'Total Activity', 
COUNT(b.Description) AS 'Total Activity (T-2 Months)', 
Sum(IIF(a.Description Like 'Outgoing Call%',1,0)) As 'Outbound Calls', 
Sum(IIF(b.Description Like 'Outgoing Call%',1,0)) As 'Outbound Calls (T-2 Months)', 
Sum(IIF(a.Description Like 'Credit%',1,0)) As 'Credit', 
Sum(IIF(b.Description Like 'Credit%',1,0)) As 'Credit (T-2 Months)', 
Sum(IIF(a.Description Like 'Correspondence Sent%',1,0)) As 'Correspondence', 
Sum(IIF(b.Description Like 'Correspondence Sent%',1,0)) As 'Correspondence (T-2 Months)' 
FROM AccountTable m INNER JOIN ActivityTable a ON m.AccountNumber=a.AccountNumber 
INNER JOIN ActivityTable_2M b On a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber 
GROUP BY m.CaseManager;
```

The query ran fine before I added the 2nd INNER JOIN (ActivityTable_2M) so I assume that there's an issue somewhere with this. I ran this query on an SQL tester and no errors were highlighted.

Comment: In MS Access you need to use parentheses when joining more than two tables.  The syntax is FROM tableA INNER JOIN (tableB INNER JOIN tableC)

Answer (score 0):

In access you need to use parenthesis `()` when when using more than one join. Please try this:

```
SELECT m.CaseManager, SUM(m.Lead) AS 'Total Leads', 
COUNT(a.Description) AS 'Total Activity', 
COUNT(b.Description) AS 'Total Activity (T-2 Months)', 
Sum(IIF(a.Description Like 'Outgoing Call%',1,0)) As 'Outbound Calls', 
Sum(IIF(b.Description Like 'Outgoing Call%',1,0)) As 'Outbound Calls (T-2 Months)', 
Sum(IIF(a.Description Like 'Credit%',1,0)) As 'Credit', 
Sum(IIF(b.Description Like 'Credit%',1,0)) As 'Credit (T-2 Months)', 
Sum(IIF(a.Description Like 'Correspondence Sent%',1,0)) As 'Correspondence', 
Sum(IIF(b.Description Like 'Correspondence Sent%',1,0)) As 'Correspondence (T-2 Months)' 
FROM (AccountTable m INNER JOIN ActivityTable a ON m.AccountNumber=a.AccountNumber) 
INNER JOIN ActivityTable_2M b On a.AccountNumber = b.AccountNumber 
GROUP BY m.CaseManager;
```

Comment: @Danny O'Sullivan please let me know if you are still facing any more problem with this query.

Answer (score 0):

In access you can't have multiple joins without separating them with parentheses. References : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23761814/syntax-error-missing-operator-in-query-expression-in-ms-access)